# Javascript loading issue in Magento's admin panel

Tags: magento

We are facing a Javascript loading issue in Magento's admin panel for the `manage products` and `manage categories` sections.

```
ReferenceError: productGridJsObject is not defined
ReferenceError: LightboxOptions is not defined
```

Please help us fix this. Thanks.

Comment: are you using any functionality in admin which used lightbox?

Comment: yes,@Muk i am using advanced manage product field manager extension which is using lightbox also.

Comment: Try disabling that extension , if after that it works then there may be some conflict with the extension js and prototype js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i reorder jquery files from layouts .xml file of extension in magento and issue is solved!!!